# Find rows in numpy array of matplotlib date objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using matplotlib.dates to convert my string dates into date objects thinking it would be easier to manipulate later.

```
import matplotlib.dates as md    
def ConvertDate(datestr):
    '''
    Convert string date into matplotlib date object
    '''
    datefloat = md.datestr2num(datestr)
    return md.num2date(datefloat)
```

What I was trying to do was filter my structured array to tell me the index numbers of rows belong to a certain month and/or year

```
import numpy as np
np.where( data['date'] == 2008 )
```

I can probably use a lambda function to convert each object into string value like so

```
lambda x: x.strftime('%Y')
```

to compare each item but I dont know where to put this lambda function into np.where or if its even possible.

Any ideas? Or is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of error messages, I think I found an answer to my own question.

```
[ x for x in range(len(data)) if data['date'][x].year == 2008 ]
```

I did a list comprehension to return the indexes of the structured array that matched a query. I also included @hayden's suggestion to use `.year` instead of `strftime()` Maybe `numpy.where()` is still faster but this suits my needs right now.

Comment: You could also use, `i for i,x in enumerate(data) ...` which I think reads cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: you might as well use datetime's [`datetime.strptime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/1240268) function:*

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('1/2/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('1/2/2011', '%d/%m/%Y')

In [5]: dt1
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

You can then use [`numpy.non-zero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) (to filter your array to the indices of those datetimes where, for example, year is 2012):

```
a = np.array([dt1, dt2])
b = np.array(map(lambda x: x.year, a))

In [8]: b
Out[8]: array([2012, 2011], dtype=bool)

In [9]: np.nonzero(b==2012)
Out[9]: (array([0]),)
```

*Also, I would suggest looking into [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) which has this functionality built-in (on top of numpy), many more convenience functions (e.g. `to_datetime`), as well as efficient datetime storage...*

Comment: So I think I did the opposite:
I created a new array that converted the object into text 
`newArray = np.array(map(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y'),data['date']))` and did the matching on that `matches = np.where( newArray == '2008')`

Therefore the match indexes are also the indexes of the original array

Comment: My code does exactly the same thing? But I think it should be more efficient to use `x.year == 2008` (since it avoid calling `strftime`).

Comment: Sorry I'm confused with `np.where(lambda x: x.year == 2012)` part. Shouldn't the `lambda` function map to `dt` when you create a new array? Anyway you are right that pandas may be better for my purpose.

Comment: Sorry, didn't properly verify what I was doing! There must be a way without using map...